# Laravel count and raw sql count gives different values

Tags: sql, laravel-5, eloquent

When i run this query in raw sql:

```
select count(postsid) as total, postsid
from posts
where postsid = 110
group by postsid
```

the value of total is 2971 (which is correct), but when is try to do this with Laravel through a relationship:

```
$item->posts->count('postsid')
```

the value that is returned is 30934 (which is wrong). Am i using the function wrong or is the problem somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss the `where` condition and `group by`

```
$item->posts
    ->select('posts.*', DB::raw('count(postsid) as total, postsid'))
    ->where('postsid', '=', 110)
    ->group_by('postsid')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! this works. I tried to add it in a with function Item::with(['posts' => function($query) {           // select and where         }]) but that did not work out

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are missing `postsid = 110` in the laravel query.

It should be `$item->posts->count('postsid',110)`

Comment: i never saw in the docs that a second argument is possible, tried it but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because COUNT(ID) returns the count of the number of not null records only. 
OR
Try the following

```
$item->posts->distinct('postsid')->count('postsid')
```